# How to determine the size of different columns in a 2D cell array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a 2D cell array where the first row consists of labels from a database, such that:

```
myData(1,:) = {'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'W'};
```

For each label, there is a column (i.e. from the second row to the last row for the particular column) that consists of cell entries, but there may be situations where not all of the cells are populated.

This example should illustrate an example of what happens with what I'm working with:

```
myData = 
    'X'    'Y'    'Z'    'W'
    [1]     []     []    [1]
    [2]     []     []    [2]
     []     []     []    [3]
```

Would it be possible to determine how many non-empty rows there are for each column of my 2D cell array, not including the first row of labels?

Comment: This is unclear. How are `MyData` and `myData`related? Where are those columns? What's the list you talk about?

Comment: Sorry Luis, my mistake...

Comment: It is still not clear...

Comment: Agree with both Luis and Matt.  Not very clear.  You have a cell array of individual characters, yet you claim that each column of this character array is different in length... yet the size of each cell is just a single character.

Comment: my present problem would be to discriminate the length size of each column. (Im sorry im trying to be clear guys)

Comment: That diagram helps.  Luis Mendo's answer is probably what you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
sum(~cellfun('isempty', myData))-1
```

The `~cellfun(...)` part gives `1` for each cell of your 2D cell array that is not empty, and `0` otherwise. Then the sum for each column is computed (`sum(...)`); and `1` is subtracted so that the first row is not considered. The result in your example is:

```
>> myData
myData = 
    'X'    'Y'    'Z'    'W'
    [1]     []     []    [1]
    [2]     []     []    [2]
     []     []     []    [3]

>> sum(~cellfun('isempty', myData))-1
ans =
     2     0     0     3
```

Comment: Yes Luis...how can I improve my question to be more clearly?

Comment: @EricHideki - I've edited your post to describe the problem better.  Let me know if you agree with the edit.  If not, I can revert back.